# Expected end of statement. How to assign two arguments?

Tags: vbscript

I have to program an impedance analyzer for work. This is done by macros which are programmed in VBS. The device has specific code lines to program it, but it's about a basic problem.
I have to use a command which wants 2 arguments to work, but I can't figure out how to assign these 2 commands.

I've already tried different types of writing this line and assigning the 2 arguments, but nothing worked so far. I've also tried to look it up on the manufactures website, but there is no defined description of how to write these commands.

```
Dim ana
Set ana = CreateObject("E4990.Application")
ana.scpi.mmemory.store.trace = "D:\data01.csv","DISP"
```

The command should save all the data that is displayed on the screen.
But instead, it either says "Expected end of statement", or "Illegal parameter value", depending on how the line is written.

A related command which saves just some of the data and only needs it's directory/filename works just fine. So there must be a problem with the 2 arguments.

And I honestly don't want to learn VBS in its full range, because I only need a few commands including this one to program the impedance analyzer.

Comment: `variable = "foo", "bar"` is not a valid construct in VBScript. If you need to assign an array of values to a variable (or object property) you need to do it like this: `variable = Array("foo", "bar")`. I'm not sure if this will work in your case, though, b/c I know nothing about the object you're working with.

Comment: "2 arguments", an assignment to a variable can only have 1 argument, is `trace` a method? Then you should remove the `=` and make it a method call, however if it is an array/collection property, you need to assign it a collection of values.

Comment: Have you tried to address the issue to a vendor of this device? He should know for sure how is it going.

Comment: BTW as I see [here](http://ena.support.keysight.com/e4990a/manuals/webhelp/eng/programming/command_reference/mmemory/mmem_stor_trac.htm), the syntax is completely different compared to your example.